# Dynamics CRM 2011 Report Filter Criteria Lookup value are 'undefined'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have some saved report in CRM 2011 , when I edit Filter Criteria to change the Values , I do not see previous values , I just see "Undefined" values in lookup.
Please check the snapshot below.

Surprisingly the report itself works fine and shows valid data.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the report has hard-coded values from a lower environment, then the IDs may not match up to the IDs in higher environments - leading to an "Undefined" lookup name.  The screenshot provided indicates that there are 8 selected values, but they all could not be resolved to a record in the system that you are running the report against (or else the lookup name could not be found, even though the ID could).

Comment: Thanks for reply @Joseph , the report is created with Report wizard in Dynamics CRM 2011, could you elaborate a bit more, what do you mean by lower env ?

Comment: I mean if you created the report in your development environment (lower environment) via the report wizard, then promoted it to a higher environment (ie testing, training, production, etc.) via a solution file.

Comment: NO , I created the report in one org and trying to edit that in the same org , and this issue is happening with many orgs in my env. Do you know any possible solution to it ?

Comment: In general, a lookup object (which is what you are selecting in the screenshot) is a combination of an id, the type, and the "name" of the record.  It appears that that name can't be found.  This means that the lookup is broken.  The usual culprit is that the id is not pointing to an existing record, or that you don't have access to the record it is pointing to - that's why I suspected it had the id of a record in another environment.  It also could be: 1) the record was deleted, 2) you don't have access to it.  navigate to the records in question, and you should have your answer.

Comment: If the report shows correct data (and its working) then can I assume that report has correct ID for records?

Comment: At risk of glossing over the original issue above - yes, if you mean that the correct data is displaying _based on the filter with the broken lookups_, then the IDs are correct and it is just a matter of the name in the lookup not working - nothing to really worry about.